# magento 2 in how to products value will be imported?

Tags: magento2.2, import, admin-panel, csv, magento-2.1.9

```
I have three csv files 
1).products attributes.
2).products details files.
3).products attributes values files .

first 2 files will be imported but attributes csv files not imported.

Error:
```

[image]

```
products attributes values not set, thus attributes values?
```

Please give me any solutions

Comment: swt_size and swt_includes  attributes doesn't have the imported values hence go to the respected attributes and add them and do reindex and again try to  import your csv file

Comment: let me know swt_size and swt_includes are drop-down fields ?

Comment: i will try to  it but not working

Comment: swt_size  it's the drop-down attribute its only get the limite of values more then values not added , and  another one it's not delete in values .?

Comment: can u share the screen shot please?

Comment: have u crated values by using script or manually ?

Comment: values will be bulk import process.  actually full files of values there but its not imported  ?

Comment: have u did re-index after created attributes and values?

Comment: i will try to that re-index but not working ?

Comment: i will change the php.ini max_input_vars-1000000 but  no response in import vaules

Comment: better do reindex from command line (and) are u trying in your local machine?

Comment: php bin/magento indexer:reindex its also tying bro

Comment: check this reference video here i am taking same example https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_haV1H7N2Jr_JyIfMBC3I5IjLp_8KkU9/view

Comment: or else try like this for at-least 3 to 5 products and import https://prnt.sc/lux7gm

Comment: i will see that video but swt_size is set  the drop-down box another i have there files 1. attributes set and create  files and another  products basic details files last file that products attribute set files. last one  not imported ?